# Create apache redirect for single page but not child pages

Tags: apache

I am trying to do a simple `Apache` `Redirect` that redirects a single page to a new URL, but not the child pages. E.g.

Redirect www.mysite.com/old to www.mysite.com/new

I do NOT want to redirect www.mysite.com/old/page1 to www.mysite.com/new/page1 or any childpages of /old.

Using a redirect like the following DOES include child pages:

```
Redirect 302 /old /new
```

**How can I only redirect the top/parent page but not the child pages?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old$
RewriteRule "(.*)" "http://www.example.com/new" [R=302,L]
```

This way you verify that the requested URI is "/old", and nothing else.

**`^/old$`** :

- `^` starts with
- `$` ends with
- `R=302`: you can put another status if you want, like 301
- `L`: last rewrite to verify, do not apply further rewrites

If you try `http://www.example.com/old/somepage.html`, it will not match the `RewriteCond` since it does not match `^/old$` and will not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/old$ /new
```